# Using hanami ORM to do autocomplete

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, wildcard, hanami

I am trying to implement autocomplete with `hanami-model` and I am trying to find in documentation or google how fetch records using `LIKE` function.

I am trying to reflect following SQL query using hanami repositories:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%a'
```

Do you know how to do this? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: With UserRepository defined try `UserRepository.new.where{ name.like('%a') }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavel is right, you can use `repo.where { name.like(pattern) }` code for work with `LIKE`/`ILIKE`.

[Here](https://github.com/davydovanton/octostar/blob/master/lib/octostar/repositories/project_repository.rb#L33-L38) you can find real example :)